# Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 optimus nvidia MX150 unknown

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a problem with Xiaomi mi notebook pro.

My specs:

- i5-8250U
- Intel HD620
- Nvidia MX150

I have tried I think almost everything till now. On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 nvidia states as unknown.

Solutions I have tried:

- installing different drivers from repositories and from official site,
- different Ubuntu versions (16.04 and 18.04),
- Updating kernel from 4.13/4.15 to 4.16,
- installing bumblebee optimus,
- Enabling/disabling secure boot

Probably I have done more things but with no success, still.

I have also noticed that on Ubuntu 18.04, when I clean install and do nothing to Nvidia drivers, Ubuntu seems to not see secondary GPU (MX150) in any way and then fans are running very rare. Any modification to drivers (switching between nouveau to nvidia and vice versa) causing Ubuntu to see additional GPU and fans are going almost constantly BUT still does not recognize GPU model.

If somebody can help me with getting Nvidia model to be recognized properly, and if not used, to be in standby, please share your knowledge.

Comment: Hey I have the same laptop and got bumblebee to work on linuxmint 19 by following comment made by kelebek333 https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/971